# Pythonic and faster way to declare dictionary, list, tuple and string?

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, dictionary, tuples

To declare a vacant dictionary we can do either `a = dict()` or by using curly braces `a = {}`. To declare a vacant list we can do either `b = []` or `b = list()`. To declare a vacant tuple we can do either `c = ()` or `c = tuple()`. Similarly to declare a vacant string we can do either `d = ""` or `d = str()`.

Moreover, in Python 3.6 `a = {}` is around 3 times faster than `a = dict()` and `b = []` is around 5 times faster than `b = list()`. Does this mean that using curly braces and brackets for declaration of new dict and list is more pythonic way compared to using `dict()` or `list()` or time-complexity has nothing to do with these two procedures being pythonic and devs prefer them at their will?

Also, which ones are faster in python 3 for declaring tuple and string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortest expressions are the fastest ones. An empty tuple is fastest to declare `c = ()` and the fastest empty string is `d = ""`.

You can measure the time yourself with

```
~$ python3 -m timeit 'a = ()'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0708 usec per loop
```